# Authorization Error while rendering the Jasper Report

Tags: urlencode, jasperserver, visualize

Occasionally getting "Unauthorized Error" when my Base64 encoded token contains a "+" sign (which is a valid Base 64 character)

I am using Visualize-JS to render the Jasper report in MVC Boilerplate. To authenticate every request, I am using the pre authorization flow where I am sending a Base64 encoded token from my application and on Jasper server decoding it.

Everything is working fine except, occasionally I am getting "Unauthorized Error". When I checked I found it is only failing when my Base64 encoded token contains a "+" sign (which is a valid Base 64 character). My C# code is URL encoding the + sign as %2B whereas the Java code while decoding the same URL  converts %2B into a space. (Note - I am encoding in C# and decoding in Java since, Jasper server only supports JAR files).

Is anyone else facing this or have faced earlier and found the solution?

For now, as a work around I am replacing the space with a + sign but, I am searching for a better solution.

Here is the faulty token, C# code for encoding and Java code for decoding

Token - f0NNFeJKfvBiWZP7I7vTGHb8yhiDEmkoE35p6ueQceBiMUJbPoaF927UsHn7w2AdCbKmfjjfZyKxm8iwrTo37kLZPE91EuT4WJrQ/KjQ+r0=

C# Code for Encryption -

```
    public string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(plainBytes, GetRijndaelManaged(_config.EncryptionKey))));
    }

    public RijndaelManaged GetRijndaelManaged(string secretKey)
    {
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
        byte[] secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
        Array.Copy(secretKeyBytes, keyBytes, Math.Min(keyBytes.Length, secretKeyBytes.Length));
        return new RijndaelManaged
        {
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            KeySize = 128,
            BlockSize = 128,
            Key = keyBytes,
            IV = keyBytes
        };
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes, RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged)
    {
        return rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
    }
```

Java Code -  encryptedText here is the token mentioned above

```
    public String decrypt(String encryptedText){
        encryptedText = decode(encryptedText);
        byte[] cipheredBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText);
        byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(secretKey);

        return new String(decrypt(cipheredBytes, keyBytes, keyBytes), "UTF-8");
    }

    public static String decode(String url)  
    {  
        try {  
            String prevURL="";  
            String decodeURL=url;  
            while(!prevURL.equals(decodeURL))  
            {  
                prevURL=decodeURL;  
                decodeURL=URLDecoder.decode( decodeURL, "UTF-8" );
            }  
            return decodeURL.replace(" ", "+");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {  
            return "Issue while decoding" +e.getMessage();  
        }  
    }

    private byte[] getKeyBytes(String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
        byte[] parameterKeyBytes= key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        System.arraycopy(parameterKeyBytes, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(parameterKeyBytes.length, keyBytes.length));
        return keyBytes;
    }
```

Comment: It might help to include examples of tokens that aren't working and some code?

Comment: Jasper server is the jasper server or some application you built?

Comment: @Druckles Added the asked details above.

Comment: it seems like you are decoding twice, java should decode `%2B` to `+`, but if you decode again it will become  ` ` (space)